# JavaScript Array not showing updated element

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple program to list some elements from an array and then the user can input a value thats gets pushed to that array, but for some reason the array is not showing the updated array. I can see the additional values getting pushed into it but the UI is not updating? Perhaps it is the order of the code?

code:

```
// Data structure
const planets = [
  'Mercury', 
  'Venus', 
  'Earth'
];
    
// Loop over array
const func = (arr) => {
let items = '';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  items += `<li>${ arr[i] }</li>`;                     
}
  return items;
}


let html = `
<ul>
  ${func(planets)}
</ul>
<button id='myButton'> Add </button>
`;

document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = html;

// add to array
const addFunc = () => {
    const searchQuery = prompt('What do you want to add?');
    const search = newArray.push(searchQuery);
}

const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addFunc();                        
});
```

Comment: The code which updates your ui is `.innerHTML = html;`, which only runs once when the page loads, as it is not inside your addFunc()

Comment: Where would be a better place to put it?

Comment: you can put the code which creates the `html` string and performs the `.innerHTML` into a function of its own (eg: updateUI). You can call this function when the page loads, and also call it once you add an item to your array. Anotther way would be to leave your code as is and use `.innerHTML = \`<li>${ searchQuery  }</li>\`;` as the last line in your addFunc

Comment: @Sole, Does this is  what you want? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/ZEQKmge

Comment: @Sole, I have made it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a common function like `getHtml(planets)` and passdown the array you have on page load.

And this function will generate `ul` , `li` via `func(planets)` and `button`

And also place the eventlistener here for the add button.

Also modify your `addFunc` like,

```
const addFunc = () => {
    const searchQuery = prompt('What do you want to add?');
    planets.push(searchQuery);
    getHtml(planets)
}
```

**Note:** You have used `newArray` in your code but you have not declared that elsewhere but trying to push an element which will trow error.

Working **Snippet** as follows,

```js
// Data structure
const planets = [
  'Mercury', 
  'Venus', 
  'Earth'
];
    
// Loop over array
const func = (arr) => {
let items = '';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  items += `<li>${ arr[i] }</li>`;                     
}
  return items;
}

const getHtml = (planets) =>{
  let html = `
<ul>
  ${func(planets)}
</ul>
<button id='myButton'> Add </button>
`;

  document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = html;

 const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
  
  myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addFunc();                        
  });
}

getHtml(planets)

// add to array
const addFunc = () => {
    const searchQuery = prompt('What do you want to add?');
    planets.push(searchQuery);
    getHtml(planets)
}
```

```html
<main> </main>
```

Comment: Thanks, newArray was left in by mistake

Comment: @Sole, Okay just keep that point in future questions.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```js
// Data structure
const planets = [
   'Mercury', 
   'Venus', 
   'Earth'
 ];
     
 // Loop over array
 const func = (arr) => {
 let items = '';
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   items += `<li>${ arr[i] }</li>`;                     
 }
   return items;
 }
 

 // add to array
 const addFunc = () => {
   const searchQuery = prompt('What do you want to add?');
   planets.push(searchQuery)

   displayHTML()
 }
 
const displayHTML = () => {
   let html = `
   <ul>
     ${func(planets)}
   </ul>
   <button id='myButton' onclick='addFunc()'> Add </button>
   `;
   
   document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = html;
}

displayHTML()

 const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
 
 myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   addFunc();                        
 });
```

Comment: Although thats nearly there, It only runs the click once

Comment: you need to remove ` <button id='myButton'> Add </button> ` from js and add it to html

Comment: or you can replace `<button id='myButton'> Add </button> ` with `<button id='myButton' onclick="addFunc()"> Add </button>` in javascript